# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function but async is already included

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I don't know why I am getting this problem, I already have async included

here is the code

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

module.exports = {
  name: "find",
  aliases: ["f"],
  run: async (message) => {
    message.attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
      const url = attachment.url;
      console.log(url);

      const res1 = await fetch(
        `https://saucenao.com/search.php?db=999&output_type=2&testmode=1&numres=16&url=${url}`
      );
      const data1 = await res1.json();
      console.log(data1);
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: You're in a nested scope, that must be async aswell. `.forEach(async attatchment =>`

Comment: The callback you give to `.forEach` is not `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "find",
  aliases: ["f"],
  run: async (message) => {
    message.attachments.forEach(async (attachment) => {
      const url = attachment.url;
      console.log(url);

      const res1 = await fetch(
        `https://saucenao.com/search.php?db=999&output_type=2&testmode=1&numres=16&url=${url}`
      );
      const data1 = await res1.json();
      console.log(data1);
    });
  },
};
```

**async** should be written in a function that has **await** method.
In your code await is written in forEach function, not in the run.

Comment: You should include *why* this worked and what you changed

Comment: thanks , the await problem has fixed but there's another problem popped up and i have no idea about it . it is TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: check whether you are getting  message.attachments as a array or not using debug.And if async issue is solved please accept solution and do not forgot to upvote the answer.thanks.